# How safe is the outlet on a stove for large appliances?

Tags: electrical

I recently acquired a portable AC unit, but have very few options for where it can be plugged in since the cord is so short.  One possibility is in our kitchen, but the only nearby outlet is on the stove itself.  If nothing else is drawing power from the outlet, is this safe at all?  What information would I need in order to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the instruction manual for the stove unit?

Comment: What are the amps/watts required by the AC unit.  Is the stove close to where you need to have the exhaust vent for the AC.  For temporary use, a short heavy duty(12 gauge) extension might be better.

Comment: @crip659 This is the product - it says not to use an extension cord: https://www.lg.com/ca_en/heating-and-cooling/lg-LP1419IVSM

Comment: I think almost every tool/appliance/device has that warning.  It is there for all the stupid people who use the cheapest 16 gauge long extensions or place them so there is a good chance of tripping/pulling hazard/place them under carpets(to heat up).   The use of listed 12 gauge of shortest length needed is allowed by code for temporary use(you unplug when not using).

Comment: Is the wall connection 3-wire or 4-wire?  3-wire is ungrounded, but because of the way they bond the range chassis to neutral, if the neutral wire breaks the range and appliances plugged into it **become energized**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.